# Ansible incremental update for loop in set_fact not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have below registered variable output. And I am trying to get the unique `tagId`s from this output.

Ansible Version: `2.9.6`

```
   "results": [
        {
            "json": [
                {
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "tagId": 123
                        },
                        {
                            "tagId": 1014
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "json": [
                {
                    "adp_release": "xxxxxx",
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "tagId": 111
                        },
                        {
                            "tagId": 1014
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Trying with the below code:**
This is only retuning the last element tags from the `results` list. Incremental update for loop in set_fact not working.

```
          - name: get all tags
            set_fact: alltags={{ item.json[0]['tags'] | map(attribute='tagId') | list |unique }}
            with_items: "{{ results }}"

          - debug: var=alltags
```

How to get a combined list of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Get the unique tagId(s)."***

A: For example, use *json_query*

```yaml
alltags: "{{ results|json_query('[].json[].tags[].tagId')|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
alltags:
  - 123
  - 1014
  - 111
```

The next option is the mapping of the attributes. For example, the expression below gives the same result

```yaml
alltags: "{{ results|map(attribute='json')|flatten|
                     map(attribute='tags')|flatten|
                     map(attribute='tagId')|list|unique }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    results:
      - json:
        - tags:
            - tagId: 123
            - tagId: 1014
      - json:
        - adp_release: xxxxxx
          tags:
            - tagId: 111
            - tagId: 1014

    alltags: "{{ results|json_query('[].json[].tags[].tagId')|unique }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: alltags
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same without `json_query`? I cant install `jamespath` module.

Comment: Yes. You can map attributes. I added the example.

Comment: getting error  with mapping `failure using method (v2_runner_on_ok) in callback plugin (<ansible.plugins.callback.default.CallbackModule object at 0x7f1d23e65a90>): Object of type set is
not JSON serializable`

Comment: `{{ results|map(attribute='json')|flatten|map(attribute='tags')|flatten|map(attribute='tagId')|list|unique }}` adding `list` at end worked. Thanks a lot.